# Android Studio shows " (Unavailable)" for Android Virtual Device choice

Tags: android-studio

I think the image is not clear but when I trying to choose Android virtual device they write next to it it's unavailable.

How can I solve this?

This problem shows up in Android Studio setup in SDK component Setut:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just a warning, after completing the wizard the Android Emulator will be downloaded and the AVD available.